# RTF Template XML Publisher

Tags: bi-publisher

In RTF Template I'm looking for the syntax for Not NULL
example- abc not ('NULL')

currently I am using

But its not working

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If your requirement is to use Not Null within conditional formatting or region it could be done like this `<?if:field!=''?>Hello World<?end if?>`
This will print **Hello World** whenever value in **field** element is not equals to null.

I hope it will help or if you are looking for something else please let me know your exact situation, may be I'll be able to help.